# Visualizing dataset on Tensorboard

Tags: tensorflow, dataset, localhost, data-visualization, tensorboard

I am reading tutorials about TensorFlow visualization and found out Tensorboard. I would like to know how can I visualize for example, [Iris](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Iris) dataset taken from UCI Machine Learning repository. I have been able to run a specified port on localhost which shows TensorBoard, but do not know how to visualize a locally taken dataset there. I searched on google but really could not find how to do. Could you help me, please ?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly then you wish to use tf.summary.image. The documentation is here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/image
Some example usage from my code is:

```
x_pl=tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,height,width,channels], name="ImageIn")
tf.summary.image('input', x_pl, 10)
```

x_pl is where I feed my image data in.
In my cummary declaration I say that I want to create a summary called 'input' and to take 10 images from x_pl.

Read the summary-writer example/tutorial here: https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/summaries_and_tensorboard

You will need to merge your summaries:

```
merged = tf.summary.merge_all()
```

You will need to declare a summary-writer a bit like this:

```
train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(FLAGS.summaries_dir + '/train',sess.graph)
```

See the above tutorial/example to understand how Tensorboard works. Not that you will want to replace the summaries with image summaries for your purposes.